# $_POST variable empty (with Ajax)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, jsgrid

I've tried to add a lign a tab which add a row in a table (in database).
I use jsgrid but I've a json error : when I try to execute PHP, I have an error on my prepare method (with the $_POST variable in the execute function).
My code :

```
switch($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]) {
    case "POST":
    var_dump($_POST);
    $result= $bdd->prepare('UPDATE t_test SET name=:name, last_name=:last_name WHERE id=:id');
    $result->execute(array(
        'name' => $_POST['name'],
        'last_name' => $_POST['last_name'],
        'id' => $_POST['id'],
        ));
    //var_dump($result);

    // header("Content-Type: application/json");
    // echo json_encode($result); 
break;
}
```

And the js part :

```
 <script>
$(function() {

$("#grid").jsGrid({
  height: "70%",
  width: "100%",
  filtering: true,
  editing: true,
  inserting: true,
  sorting: true,
  paging: true,
  autoload: true,

controller: {
            insertItem: function(item) {
                return $.ajax({
                    url: "items.php",
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType : "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    data: item,
                    dataType: "json",
                });
            },
  })
})
```

Here you can find [the jsgrid documentation](http://js-grid.com/docs/#grid-controller)
Thanks for your help.

The error :

> SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the       JSON dataCharge **Notice**:
>
> Undefined index: name in **jsgrid\items.php** **Notice**:
>
> Undefined index: last_name in **jsgrid\items.php** **Notice**:
>   Undefined index: id in **jsgrid\items.php**
>
> {"queryString":"UPDATE t_test SET name=:name, last_name=:last_name WHERE id=:id"}

The request : https://framapic.org/tnYXF3o0ZHjz/AumuvhieAYAW.PNG
The answer : https://framapic.org/R8BJm7CfHnSl/QDAan6IVKdER.PNG

Comment: Where to you put something into `item`

Comment: Item is the new row I've created (http://js-grid.com/docs/#grid-controller)

Comment: I dont think your `contentType` is adding anything useful, and might be causing a problem

Comment: It would also be useful to see ALL the error message you are getting

Comment: You are BOUND _pun intended_ to get a Mysql error if your $_POST is empty, you need to be looking at WHY the $_POST is empty. Are you using the javascript debugger in your browser?

Comment: I have no idea what `item` is? Is it a javascript scalar variable, an object or something else? PS most of us will not read the documentation for you even if you post a link to it. Thats your job.

Comment: Removed WHAT? Please be specific

Comment: I removed the contentType but nothing has changed

Comment: Like I said above. The MYSQL is BOUND to fail if you are not passing anything to the PHP Script in $_POST. **You need to be looking at the javascript and working out what you should really be passing on the `data:` property as a parameter** Because obviously you are NOT passing what you hoped you were passing

Comment: I have added `jsgrid` to your tags. Hopefully someone with experience of that library will see the question now and be able to help